# Protect MySQL Server on Compute Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, debian, google-compute-engine

I have an app running on App Engine standard environment but the database is on a Compute Engine instance. App Engine standard environments have no static IP that I could white list on the Compute Engine instance.
The only way to have App Engine access the database is to allow all IPs to connect to it, which is a potentially baaad bad idea.
I'd like to keep the app on App Engine standard environment and not use CloudSQL owing to the pricing factor.
What other ways can I protect the SQL server since it's open to all IPs.

Comment: **potentially** ?? Bit of an understantement :)

Comment: Are both the app and instance on the same project/network and are you able to restrict access to your database VM by only having an internal IP ?

Comment: @Gustavo They are on different projects.

Comment: @Gustavo Even if they were on the same project, that does not mean same network. The VM has an internal IP, but that only applies to applications running on Compute Engine itself.

Comment: If the two are on the same network or connected via Cloud VPN or Network Peering you can use Serverless VPC Access [1] [2]. It designed to enable a secure connection between App Engine Standard and your compute instances                                   
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access
[2]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc

Comment: Cool ... Will sure explore Serverless VPC will explore it see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect from an App Engine app directly to a Compute Engine instance, I would suggest looking into [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc). Requests are sent through your app via Serverless VPC Access to the internal IP of your instance.

[Steps to create the connector](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/connecting-vpc):

```
gcloud components update

gcloud services enable vpcaccess.googleapis.com

gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create CONNECTOR_NAME --network=VPC_NETWORK --region=REGION --range=IP_RANGE
```

Make sure you have the proper permissions and non overlapping IP range set up.

Afterwards add the code below to your app's yaml file and deploy your app.

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME"
```

You can also look into configuring a [VM as a network proxy](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#proxyvm). In this situation you would have one VM that is open to the internet and with that VM you can [securely connect to your database instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances).